# How to protect power strips from accidental shut-offs/"cleaning lady" attack?

Tags: electrical-power, uptime

Are there any power strips or products designed to defend against a "cleaning lady" attack (cleaning crew is vacuuming the floor and bumps the power strip switch, turning off all the connected equipment)?

I have some curious felines in my house that always seem to work their way behind my desk and accidentally step on the power strip switch.

Is there some sort of switch cover I can get, or a power strip that is less susceptible to this kind of problem?

Comment: tape the switch.

Comment: Mount the strip to the desk. seriously?

Comment: http://diy.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, but I can't accept any one of these answers unless they are put in an actual answer :)

Comment: @voretaq7 Closed, Reopened, Closed again, Reopened again. And now I can't vote to close again because "You have already voted to close this question" ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @ChrisS Dunt lookit me -- I'm refraining from voting on this one 'cuz I done editititedidied it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One cheap way is to get yourself a dozen or so 9-12" zip-ties.

- Use a staple-gun to place a 2-3 zip-ties on the underside/back of your desk.  Place a couple staples spaced to the the width of your power strip.
- Look at your power strip to get the spacing right.
- Put the power-strip in place and then close the zip-tie.

[image: zip tie]

A bit neater is to simply get a few cable mount rings.  If get 5-6 and space these out about every 8-12" then you can collect a large number of cables to the under-side of your desk. This should make the cables/power strips immune from vacuums and so on.

[image: cable rings]

Comment: +1 for cable management options.  (though I would suggest [Velcro straps](http://www.amazon.com/Velcro-Cable-Tie-Roll-yards/dp/B000I97FJ2) (cut thinly) over zip ties.

Comment: Those too.  I just mentioned zip-ties and staples because it is really cheap.  You could do the entire project for less then a $1.  Velcro would be a little more expensive.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from completely replacing your power strip (with one that has a key switch), try a [switch cover](http://datacover.com/).

That particular site is where we got AC panel covers at my last job, but there are other places that probably have small versions suitable for power strips.

Comment: That site has the correct size for power strips, but they're $30+.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a master/slave power distributor. Put your PC/whatever your main device is into the master-slot, all other (secondary) devices to the slave-slots. If you turn on the device on the master-slot all other slots get power, too (and vice versa).

This works without a manual switch and should solve your problem.

Comment: This stops the cat from walking on the power switch how exactly??

Comment: @ChrisS well - there is no switch to step on.

Answer (score 1):

I had thought of inventing some sort of cover but found it has already been done! Google "power strip power button cover". There are plenty of little covers that easily attach to the strip and protect the bower button from accidental shut offs.

Comment: I searched as you suggested and didn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

I always just open up the power strip and solder the two leads on the power switch together. I generally make a notation on the side of the power strip that the switch has been disabled.

Comment: That sounds safe...

Comment: I can't think of any specific reason it's not safe, but I admit, I've always had a slightly uneasy feeling about it.

Comment: It's safe if (1) you know what you're doing, and (2) you're not an idiot and doing it on live power.  Given the choice I'd epoxy the switch in the "on" position instead: Nearly equal permanence, and I don't have to unscrew anything :)

Comment: @voretaq7: I didn't think of that. I like that better. It's easier, safer, and in the unlikely chance of some bizarre emergency, it makes it much more obvious that trying to flip the switch will not cut power.

Answer (score 0):

Two drops of hot-glue suffice to temporarily fixate a power plug.

Comment: Why not?  It's non-conductive.

Comment: One probably won't even reach there, when injecting 2 drops, to the left & right... and I wouldn't be too certain it's not conductive, while it's still liquid; I have no clue... and electrical work made me paranoid (only trusting voltmeter & rotary field tester).

Comment: Hot glue is non conductive even when liquid.

Answer (score 0):

I always duct tape a quarter over the power button to keep the cats from switching it off.

Comment: That could get expensive after a while.

Comment: I've been recycling the same quarter for the last 10 years! Very cheap compared to the other options! Simple, too!

Comment: I have a lot of power strips. :)

Comment: Better switch to goldfish.

Comment: On some power strips the power switch is also the circuit breaker.  Putting tape and/or coinage on such setups is a fire hazard.

Answer (score 0):

Use switch guard -- effective against accidental switch trip while avoiding the dangers of preventing emergency switch flip.

find on Amazon:
[https://www.amazon.com/Option-Switch-Guards-Clear-Toggle/dp/B00DTXKOTM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DTXKOTM)
This is NOT an affilate link -- pure information.

Comment: That is completely useless for a power strip.  That only works for wall switches.